# Tool to verify the optimal packing of all structures in a C program

Tags: c, alignment, structure, padding

Is there any tool that could verify the alignment of all structures in a particular set of C files and let us know the improperly packed structures so that proper packing(padding) can be done manually ? Is there any tool that would also do the necessary modification(padding) of the strucutures as per the required alignment and give the resultant files ?

The tool should ensure that the compiler does not leave holes in the structure, so that the structures are optimally packed (without resorting to `#pragma pack` or other such tricks), and would reorder items within the structure to minimize such holes.

Please let me know if any such tool exists in either Windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can specify the alignment of a structure directly in the source.

Comment: Question doesn't really make sense - the compiler determines the alignment of structs, unless you override this with e.g. #pragmas. What are you *really* trying to do ? What's the motivation ?

Comment: Are you looking to avoid holes in the structure, so that the structures are optimally packed (without resorting to `#pragma pack` or other such tricks)?

Comment: @Paul R : I am trying to avoid the holes in the structures. The problem is that, i have lot of structures and whenever i make a change in the various structures, i need to manually calculate the size and do the modifications if it is unaligned. Hence, i am looking for a tool that could help in determination of the alignment of all the structures in the particular set of C based files and tell the unaligned structures.It would also be great if that tool can automatically align the unaligned structures to the specific alignment value for that particular environment.

Comment: @S.Man: OK - I think the confusion here is coming from the fact that you're overloading the term "unaligned" to mean "not optimally packed".

Comment: Yes, "unaligned" does _not_ mean there's excess padding. Using the term incorrectly will cause confusion, so please clarify what you mean by "unaligned" and edit the question to fit :)

Comment: I have often had the need to know what the alignment of not only the structure itself but each member of the structure. Being in embedded software, I often have the need to manage EEPROM data using external tools and generate an S-Record with the data for programming either at module manufacturing or in the field reprogramming.

I have never found a tool that will do this. I have written some very specific single use tools over the years but I would also like to find a tool that could be configured with all the different alignment rules I've run across.

Comment: Nothing at compile time, but at runtime we've used combinations of offsetof() and sizeof() to make sure packing is being done "as expected."  We're usually looking to make sure that structs match an existing "on disk" layout.    Something could be added to your test suite to do a similar task.   It has pointed out issues with an adjustment to a datatype which the compiler then decides to pad all fields to the highest common size...

Comment: @S.Man: Each compiler has its own rules (modulo the standard) about how it packs structures based on sizes of the various fields. Such a tool would thus necessarily be compiler dependent. (Which compiler are you using?) I'm still unclear on the actual problem you want to solve; can't you use "sizeof(...)" to "calculate the size"? And what specific "modifications" are you referring to? Normally if the compiler assigns members, it will also change the code it generates to access those members. Finally, why do you object to using "pragma pack" (a kind of tool) and insist on a different tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very hard to write a tool to do this job because C is such an uncontrolled language with the preprocessor available to mess everything up.  You need to analyze the preprocessed code, and relate that back to the source.  The easy part is working out the alignment rules for the basic types.  You can use a series of structures such as:

```
struct a_double { char byte; double d; };
```

The required alignment for the type is `offsetof(struct a_double, d)`.

You then need to parse the source structure, working out the alignments of each member.  However, you also have to be prepared to deal with:

```
struct something
{
    int a;
    struct x
    {
        char b;
        double c;
        short s;
    } d[12];
    union y
    {
        void (*function)(void);
        struct z
        {
            char f[23];
            int  g;
        } p;
        void *vp;
    } e;
};
```

That is decidedly non-trivial.  But you also have to remember that in the source, it may have looked like:

```
struct something
{
     TYPE1 a;
     TYPE2 d[12];
     TYPE3 e;
};
```

And the *TYPEn* types might be typedefs, or macros, or macros identifying typedefs, or some other distortion of normality.  In such a case, what is the tool to do?  Does it have to work out the mapping between the `struct something` written in the source and the `struct something` that is generated by the pre-processor?  It requires a significant portion of a C compiler to handle all this, which is probably why there are so few tools available to do the job.

If your data structures are simple, you can apply some simple heuristics and come up with a 'good enough' solution, but the full generality of what happens is non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a tool to do the rearrangement for you, but if you're using GCC, you can compile with `-Wpadded` to have it warn you if it inserts padding into any structs, so that should at least be an easy way to check for added padding.